# Can't save a $_REQUEST method in database 2

Tags: php, mysql

I can't save a `$_GET` method to database, but it has no error. it has a empty record in database.

```
<form action="customizeText.php?" method="get" >
            <?php
                $customizeName =  '1set';
                $customizePrice = $_GET['p'];
                $customizeColor1 = $_GET['c1'];
                $customizeColor2 = $_GET['c2'];
                $customizeColor3 = $_GET['c3'];
                $customizeText1 = 'I';
                $customizeText2 = 'L';
                $customizeText3 = 'U';
                $customizePackage = 'red';
                $quantity = 1;
            ?>

            <div><strong><?php echo $customizeName; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$customizePrice; ?></div>
            <?php echo $customizeColor1; ?>
            <?php echo $customizeColor2; ?>
            <?php echo $customizeColor3;?>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" name="btnAddAction" /></div>

</form>

<?php     
if (isset($_GET['btnAddAction'])) { 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO customizeproduct (custProName, custProPrice, custProColor1, custProColor2, custProColor3, custProText1, custProText2, custProText3, custProPackage) VALUES ('$customizeName', '$customizePrice', '$customizeColor1', '$customizeColor2', '$customizeColor3', '$customizeText1', '$customizeText2', '$customizeText3', '$customizePackage')";
                if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
                    echo "SAVE IN DB";
                        }else{
                            echo "NO WAY";  
                        }
```

Also, I try to echo the `$customizeColor1`, `2`, `3`, it can display the data. Stack Overflow, I don't know why I can't save the data in database.

- the `$_GET["p"]`,  `$_GET["c1"]`,  `$_GET["c2"]`,  `$_GET["c3"]` is in the path , like this : `customizeText.php?p=399&c1=Blue&c2=Red&c3=Green`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Thank you for edit my question as i use this website first time. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

omg I did it, the solution is like this

```
<form action="customizeText.php?" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['p'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="c1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['c1'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="c2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['c2'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="c3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['c3'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
            <?php
                $customizeName =  '1set';
                $customizePrice = $_POST['p'];
                $customizeColor1 = $_POST['c1'];
                $customizeColor2 = $_POST['c2'];
                $customizeColor3 = $_POST['c3'];
                $customizeText1 = 'I';
                $customizeText2 = 'L';
                $customizeText3 = 'U';
                $customizePackage = 'red';
                $quantity = 1;
            ?>
            <div><strong><?php echo $customizeName; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$_GET['p']; ?></div>
            <?php echo $_GET['c1']; ?>
            <?php echo $_GET['c2']; ?>
            <?php echo $_GET['c3'];?>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" name="btnAddAction" /></div>

</form>

<?php     
if (isset($_POST['btnAddAction'])) { 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO customizeproduct (custProName, custProPrice, custProColor1, custProColor2, custProColor3, custProText1, custProText2, custProText3, custProPackage) VALUES ('$customizeName', '$customizePrice', '$customizeColor1', '$customizeColor2', '$customizeColor3', '$customizeText1', '$customizeText2', '$customizeText3', '$customizePackage')";
    if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
        echo "SAVE IN DB";
    }else{
        echo "NO WAY";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Even if it works, that's a terrible design. Your processing of the data passed from the form should be in a completely different file. For instance, your form is just a **view** and it should not be mixed with an actual **transaction**. So this file could be perfectly called `theForm.php` which action posts to `theProcessing.php` and that file then redirects to `theSuccessMessage.php` or `theForm.php` or whatever. At least use something similar to the **model view controller** design principle.

Comment: Thank you for your commnet , i will try it. I m still a learner, this is a good concept for me